Global dimension of the endomorphism ring of a Noetherian module vs. that of a finite direct sum of copies of it
Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring (not necessarily commutative). Let $M$ be a finitely generated left $A$-module and $n>1$ be an integer. Then, is it true that the global dimension of $\text{End}_A(M)$ is at most the global dimension of $\text{End}_A(M^{\oplus n})$?
If needed, I am willing to assume that the center $Z(A)$ is Noetherian and $A$ is finitely generated as a module over $Z(A)$.

I don't know a direct reference for this, but $\mathrm{End}_A(M)$ and $\mathrm{End}_A(M^{\oplus n})$ happen to be Morita equivalent and Morita equivalence preserves global dimension, hence they have the same global dimension.
More details: $\mathrm{End}_A(M^{\oplus n}) \cong M_{n\times n}(\mathrm{End}_A(M))$ and for any ring $R$, we have that $M_{n \times n}(R)$ is Morita equivalent to $R$.
To see that global dimension is Morita invariant, use the characterization as the supremum over the injective dimension of all modules.
